# how to compute this definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

it is the second moment of logistic distribution, i.e.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 e^x }{(1+e^x)^2}dx
$$
I've been struggling with it for hours. but i fail.

thanks first!

Comment: Its value equals $ 3.2898681336964528729448303332920503784378998024136 .$

Comment: @user64494: Yes, but I need an analytic solution. :-)

Comment: @ zhimengfan: What for?

Comment: @user64494： I've known,it's $\pi^2/3$, but I resort to mathematica. I don't know how to get it by hand.

Comment: @ zhimengfan: Maple produces the same. My question remains open: What for is an analytic solution needed?

Comment: @user64494: I just want to know the derivation process. :-)

Comment: @user64494, most mathematics departments in most more or less decent universities still require from their student to do some thinking and reasoning from time to time and *not* merely input stuff in computing programs and write down the results...go figure! One of the many reasons for this weird requirement is that not few times the results shown by programs are wrong.

Comment: @ zhimengfan: The definite integral is a number which is used in science or/and ingineering. This number is calculated with ceratain accuracy. It can be done simpler by numeric methods in many cases.

Comment: @ DonAntonio: As well as done by  human.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2} e^{x}}{(1+e^{x})^{2}} \ dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2} e^{x}}{(1+e^{x})^{2}} = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n e^{-nx} \ dx $$

$$ = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2} e^{-nx} \ dx = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n \Big(\frac{2}{n^{3}} \Big) $$

$$ = 4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2}} =4 \Big(\frac{\pi^{2}}{12} \Big) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{3}$$